# AWS PutObjectResponse.ETag Mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to verify an S3 Put Object using a local hash impl as follows:

```
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte byt in hash)
{
    sb.Append(byt.ToString("X2"));
}

return sb.ToString().ToLower();
```

From AWS Documentation this should match the PutObjectResponse.ETag property which is based on the content body (not Meta) of my put request.  In this case I cam posting a JSON document which is the source of my hash.

All is fine except when I use AWS Managed KMS Server-side encryption at which point my hashes do not match.  Is it not possible to verify the content body to that posted since it appears the ETAG hash is based on the encrypted content body, not the origional PUT content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to verify the integrity of the content/body using the ETag, because, as documented, the ETag no longer matches the expected value when using SSE with KMS keys.

However, you can prevent S3 from *accepting* an incomplete or corrupted upload, by sending a `Content-MD5` header with the upload.  The value you supply will be the binary (not hex) md5 of the payload, encoded in base64, and not url-escaped.  If the payload doesn't match this hash, S3 won't accept the upload or store the object, and will return an error.

The SDK you are using might do this for you automatically, or you may he able to enable it; I don't know, since I use my own written-from-scratch libraries for all AWS service interactions.